# Confirm String is a Substring (regardless of order)

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a code trying to return `True` if a substring exist within a string

Example 1:

```
str1 = 'Wolverine vs Freddy Krueger'
str2 = 'Freddy Krueger Vs Wolverine'

str2.find(str1) # returns -1 (False)
```

What would be the simplest way to return True in this and other situations like this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to check if all words from one string are present in another string?

Comment: In a way, yes. Ideally, the most cost effective one, as my code is pretty cost heavy at the moment.

Comment: Use `split` to create a list of the words. Then you can use `set` or `collections.Counter` to create sets or multisets and check for equality, subset or superset.

Answer (score 0):

First, make the substring and full_string lowercase, split into lists, and convert them to sets. Now check, if the sub_string_set is a subset of the full_string_set. Gave some examples to clarify.

```
def is_substring_in_string(substring, full_string):
    # Split both strings into sets of words (ignoring case)
    substring_set = set(substring.lower().split())
    full_string_set = set(full_string.lower().split())

    # Check if the substring set is a subset of the full string set
    return substring_set.issubset(full_string_set)

# Example 1
str1 = 'Wolverine vs Freddy Krueger'
str2 = 'Freddy Krueger Vs Wolverine'
result = is_substring_in_string(str1, str2)
print(result)  # Output: True

# Example 2
str1 = 'Wolverine vs Freddy Krueger'
str2 = 'The Freddy Krueger Vs Wolverine'
result = is_substring_in_string(str1, str2)
print(result)  # Output: True

# Example 3
str1 = 'The Wolverine vs Freddy Krueger'
str2 = 'Freddy Krueger Vs Wolverine'
result = is_substring_in_string(str1, str2)
print(result)  # Output: True
```